# Matlab: Percenatge calculation and plotting

Tags: matlab

I have a text file (values.txt) with different values like this:

```
100
334
400
500
245
254
1448
1448
600
1448
1448
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of each value and plot it in matlab. Like the value 1448 is present 4 times in the text file. Which fucntions in matlab will help me to achieve the above task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hist` to count how many times each value appears. However, since your numbers are not evenly dstributed, you might need to work harder using `histc` and define the bins' edges manually.
Alternatively, you can use `unique` to determine the number of unique elements in your data set to be used as bins' centers.

```
xx = unique( vals );
nn = hist( vals, xx );
figure; bar( xx, nn ); title('counts');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the unique values and number of times they have appeared. In Matlab  `count_unique` function, you may find  the way to quickly count the number of instances of unique values within an array:

```
[uniques,numUnique] = count_unique(arrayname);
```

After that you can divide the occurrence value with the total array length. Please find the details [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23333-determine-and-count-unique-values-of-an-array)

You can also use `hist` as mentioned in [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905921/1714410).